# Bootstrap Twitter Popup works only for the first record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I have the following view in my Ruby on Rails application. I want to be able to display a content of a .txt File (the path is saved in `<%=file.info%>`) with a popup. I included already a form for a popup. The problem is in the javascript. If I place the following javascirpt before `form_tag`

**EDIT**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $("#blob").popover({ title: 'info' });
  });
</script>
```

it works only for the first record, another Info-buttons do not popup. And theoretically, i have to put the javascript after `<div class="my_view">` but then it does not work at all.

```
<%= form_tag what_to_do_files_path, method: :get do %>
<%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'pictures' do %> Analyze<% end %>
<button type="button" id="check_all" class="btn"> Check/Uncheck all</button>
<%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-warning", :name => 'delete' do %>Delete <% end %> 

<% @files.each do |file| %>
<div class="my_view"> 

 <p><td></td><%= check_box_tag "fils[]", file.id %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= file.name %></p>
  <% laa=File.read("#{Rails.root}"+"/public"+file[info]) %>
  <a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="<%= laa %>">hover for popover</a>
```

SO, my question is: How can I display the .txt File for each record, saved in the database ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking about by why don't store data in db, but in a text file on the server instead?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I have edited my question. My problem is that a popup window does not work for each record, it works only for the first one

Comment: I was asking about something else.

Comment: I do not need this data in the db and the user should see the content of the file as it is standardized in a package for R statistical language

Comment: What is this `<td>` doing out there? How does the generated code look like? (attach ALL of it please, not only first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an ID to tag your "blob", use a class. You are only allowed to have one instance of an ID per page.

When calling `$("#blob").popover({ title: 'info' });`, it's going to go for the first instance of `id="blob"` that it finds. If you change it to a class, you can write

```
$(".blob").popover({ title: 'info' });
```

and it should work for all items which have the class `blob`.